# DLOOKUP function multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a database where I want to manage three tables: files, client, meeting_dates. Each file has multiple meeting dates and refer to multiple clients. 
Two of the meeting dates are the most important dates, the date of signing the contract and the date of closing the file and these have specific strings set in another column in the dates table (sign and close) 
All three tables are linked by the ID of the file (fileID), which is unique value.

I want to generate a report based on the files table which will contain, for every individual file, the date of signing the contract and the date of closing the file, the names of the parts and the number of parts.
I don’t want to use subreports, only text boxes, because the report is intended to be a letter with sentences and the formulas will be inside the sentences. An example of the sentence is – The case number “Case_number” was signed on “Date” with the clients “Clients” and closed on “Date.

The formula I have tried is.

```
=DLookUp("[Date]";"[tbl.Dates]";"[fileID]=" & [fileID] And [type]='sign')
```

but it doesn't show any date at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with corrected concatenation:

```
=DLookUp("[Date]";"[tbl.Dates]";"[fileID]=" & [fileID] & " And [type]='sign'")
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a problem understanding the correct concatenation. So far, I have managed to „reverse-engineer” some formulas, only to adapt to my files, but I don't fully understand them, yet.